# Python Heat Distribution Plotting

Tags: python, plot, heatmap, distribution, fluid-dynamics

i have been trying to simulate a flow distribution in a space but couldn't figure out how to properly do it in python using matplotlib,seaborn,plotly etc.

I have 3 variables

X : 0 to 0.4 ( meshed to 142 pieces )

Y : 0 to 0.45 ( meshed to 17767 pieces )

T : Values starting from 300 Kelvin and distrubited along the room ( 142x17767 )

To explain more, I have a rectangular area which is 142x17767 and i want to plot heat distrubition on every point. I have tried seaborn's heatmap and hist2d from matplotlib but these methods require x and y dimension to have same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is I think [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html). Here is a sample answer. You can replace `T` below by your actual T-values. The reason you get the error is because on such a 2d heat map, you need to create a meshgrid of your x and y points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))

X = np.linspace(0, 0.4, 142)
Y = np.linspace(0, 0.45, 17767)

Xmesh, Ymesh = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

T = np.random.randint(300, 1000, Xmesh.shape)

plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, T)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this method did what i want. But actually it would be great if i can scale the sensitivity of the colormap between 300-350 because there is a region on the map which makes temperature equal to zero and that leads scaling to be between 0-350 so changes between 300-350 are not really visible. Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Comment: @TolgaOĞUZ: Try passing vmin=300, vmax=350 in plt.pcolormesh